# AWK match on term. Columns don't line up

Tags: awk

Been trying to figure this one out for a while now. Went through this site and googled like crazy.  It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help.

I have some log files with no headers and columns are all over the place.  Meaning that an item like src=4.2.2.2 could be anywhere in the file. All objects in the file do have a something=xxx format.

Example Log:

> src=1.1.1.1 sport=12312 dport=80 message=hacked
>
> dport=443 src=2.2.2.2 message=null sport=32432
>
> message=clean dport=21 sport=43434 src=3.3.3.3

I have used the match() function, but am trying to pull out multiple fields.

> gawk 'match($0, "src=([^ ]+)") { print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) } ' file

gives me the following:

> src=1.1.1.1
>
> src=2.2.2.2
>
> src=3.3.3.3

I would like to have multiple fields like src, dport and message so the output lines up and looks like the following:

> src=1.1.1.1 dport=80 message=hacked
>
> src=2.2.2.2 dport=443 message=null
>
> src=3.3.3.3 dport=21 message=clean

Is this possible with gawk or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: So basically you want to take a list with four fields in random order, remove/ignore one of them (`sport`) and output the other three in a predefined order (`src`, `dport`, `message`). Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution (independent of item positions):

```
awk 'function get_item(name){ 
         match($0, name"=[^[:space:]]+"); 
         return substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) 
     }
     { print get_item("src"), get_item("dport"), get_item("message") }' file
```

With the above approach you are able to output the crucial needed items in any order.

The output:

```
src=1.1.1.1 dport=80 message=hacked
src=2.2.2.2 dport=443 message=null
src=3.3.3.3 dport=21 message=clean
```

Comment: Elegant extension of the OP's methodology - I like it

Comment: That's awesome.  Should have just asked in here first.

Comment: Another quick question.  How would I include spaces in output?  Like if "message=something something something"

Comment: @mrusenet, "Another quick question" does not mean "quick solution". That's another story for another case, not the current one

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, thanks for the help.  I'll keep at it.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk (NOTE: this relies on the lexical sort order of the "key" strings):

```
gawk '{split($0,a); asort(a); printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", a[4], a[1], a[2])}' file
src=1.1.1.1     dport=80        message=hacked
src=2.2.2.2     dport=443       message=null
src=3.3.3.3     dport=21        message=clean
```